# How can i print rich text Box value (which is in HTML format) in jasper reports?

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports, report

I am working on a project (on java) where i have give rich text box for description. Now client wants to print that description in reports. Currently i am using jasper reports for reports. Please help me, how can i print that description in jasper report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Markup to your language (HTML, RTF, Styled)

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="140" y="53" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement markup="html"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: I am geeting this Error (Error:  Attribute "markup" must be declared for element type "textElement".   )

Comment: Ohh i am getting this error because of version.

Comment: It is much easier to do using the propriety window in i-report,  the setting is in the text Properties section about 1/2 way down (in version 4.1.1)

Comment: I am not getting your point please explain more. If you can. Thanks